# How to Apply Fill Color Depending on the Cell Value Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have this code below. If the cell is blank, the fill will be green (4). When the cell is not blank, there will be no fill. But what if I want my cell ***(0,3)*** to fill with yellow if the cell value = "YES"? Currently have a dropdown menu for "YES" or "NO".

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then


        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        If Target = "YES" Then
            For i = 1 To 9
                With Target.Offset(0, i)
                    .Locked = False
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(" & Target.Offset(0, i).Address & ")"
                    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                        .SetFirstPriority
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    End With
                End With
            Next i

       '==============================================================================================================
       '==============================================================================================================

        ElseIf Target = "NO" Then

                For i = 10 To 15
                With Target.Offset(0, i)
                    .Locked = False
                    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(" & Target.Offset(0, i).Address & ")"
                    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                        .SetFirstPriority
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    End With
                End With
            Next i

        Else

                For i = 1 To 15
                    With Target.Offset(0, i)
                        .Value = ""
                       .Locked = True
                        .FormatConditions.Delete
                    End With
                Next i

        End If

        ActiveSheet.Protect

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: There is a difference between a cell and an offset, which one do you mean? (Also, there is no `Cell(0,27)`, the index starts `1`

Answer (score 1):

See the addition below

```
    For i = 26 To 28

        With Target.Offset(0, i)
            .Locked = False
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(" & Target.Offset(0, i).Address & ")"
            With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            End With
        End With
        If i = 27 AND UCase(Target.Offset(0,i).value) = "YES" Then Target.Offset(0,i).Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0)
    Next i
```

Comment: @PeterS is the value in the offset cell (0,27) _exactly_ "YES"?

Comment: I already figured out the problem. First im going to select "YES" or "NO" in column A. Then cell offset (0, 26) to (0,28) will be filled with orange. This is under the "worksheet_change" sub. Now, Do I need to create another sub for this?

Comment: I have updated my code. I cannot apply conditional formatting for this because in my "Else" statament, when the user select "None" on the Dropdown menu in Column A. formatting will be deleted in the that row

Answer (score 0):

Then use Color = 65535 if range.value = "YES"